# android - implementing room with Kotlin Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I want to use Room with Coroutine database, this is my code so far:

This is my DAO:

```
@Dao
interface MainDao{
    // 1: Select All
    @Query("SELECT * FROM MainData")
    suspend fun getMainData(): List<MainData>

    // 2: Insert
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertMainData(mainData: MainData)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateMainData(mainData: MainData)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteTask(mainData: MainData)

    // 3: Delete
    @Query("DELETE FROM MainData")
    suspend fun deleteAllMainData()
}
```

This is my repository class:

```
class MainRepository(application: Application) : BaseRepository() {

    val api: MainApi = ApiConnection.client.create(MainApi::class.java)

    private val mainDao: MainDao
    val db = DataBase.getInstance(application)

    init {
        mainDao = db.mainDao()
    }

    suspend fun getMain(): MainData? {
        return safeApiCall(
                call = {
                    api.getMainData().await()
                },
                error = "Error fetching news"
        )
    }
}
```

I'm using retrofit for retrieving the data and it works fine and returns the value, the next step is adding Room to the project.

To do so, I first need to save the data in the room database, where and how I should save the data.

Here I get the response from the server and returns to the viewModel, where should I save data in database:

```
return safeApiCall(
    call = {
        api.getMainData().await()
    },
    error = "Error fetching news"
)
```

Comment: Room supports LIveData out of the box why are you not using that?

Comment: Inside the `call` lambda I guess? Depends on your requirements. Are you just using the database as a cache or are you logging or...?

Comment: can you try without .await() method?

Comment: and also can you share your @Entity class with us?